# GridBagLayout anchor

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to use Anchor for setting the alignment of my components.
Here is my code:

```
public void intiConOpt()
{
    /*********************************** connection options ****************************************/
    
    conOptGBC.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    conOptGBC.weightx = 1.0;
    conOptGBC.weighty = 1.0;
    conOptGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    conOpt = new JPanel();
    conOpt.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////cycle time////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    readPeriodLabel = new JLabel("Node read cycle time:");
    conOptGBC.gridx = 0;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 0;
    conOpt.add(readPeriodLabel, conOptGBC);
    
    readPeriodNumberModel = new SpinnerNumberModel();
    readPeriodSpinner = new JSpinner(readPeriodNumberModel);
    JSpinner.NumberEditor readPeriodEditor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(readPeriodSpinner,"###");
    readPeriodSpinner.setEditor(readPeriodEditor);
    readPeriodNumberModel.setValue(TopologyMain.settings.getSettingsList().get("nodeReadingCycleTime"));

    readPeriodSpinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));
    conOptGBC.gridx = 1;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 0;
    conOpt.add(readPeriodSpinner, conOptGBC);
    
    readPeriodLabel2 = new JLabel("<html><font size=2>(4-180 sec)</font></html>");
    conOptGBC.gridx = 2;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 0;
    conOpt.add(readPeriodLabel2, conOptGBC);
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////time out////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    cliTimeoutLabel = new JLabel("CLI response timeout:");
    conOptGBC.gridx = 0;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 1;
    conOpt.add(cliTimeoutLabel, conOptGBC);
    
    cliTimeoutNumberModel = new SpinnerNumberModel();
    cliTimeoutSpinner = new JSpinner(cliTimeoutNumberModel);
    JSpinner.NumberEditor cliTimeoutEditor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(cliTimeoutSpinner,"###");
    cliTimeoutSpinner.setEditor(cliTimeoutEditor);
    cliTimeoutNumberModel.setValue(TopologyMain.settings.getSettingsList().get("cliTimeout") /10);

    cliTimeoutSpinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));
    conOptGBC.gridx = 1;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 1;
    conOpt.add(cliTimeoutSpinner, conOptGBC);
    
    cliTimeoutLabel2 = new JLabel("<html><font size=2>(8-999 sec)</font></html>");
    conOptGBC.gridx = 2;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 1;
    conOpt.add(cliTimeoutLabel2, conOptGBC);
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////busy response//////////////////////////////////////////////
            
    cliBusySleepLabel = new JLabel("CLI busy check time:");
    conOptGBC.gridx = 0;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 2;
    conOpt.add(cliBusySleepLabel, conOptGBC);
    
    cliBusySleepNumberModel = new SpinnerNumberModel();
    cliBusySleepSpinner = new JSpinner(cliBusySleepNumberModel);
    JSpinner.NumberEditor cliBusySleepEditor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(cliBusySleepSpinner,"###");
    cliBusySleepSpinner.setEditor(cliBusySleepEditor);
    cliBusySleepNumberModel.setValue(TopologyMain.settings.getSettingsList().get("cliBusySleep") /1000);
    
    cliBusySleepSpinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));
    conOptGBC.gridx = 1;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 2;
    conOpt.add(cliBusySleepSpinner, conOptGBC);
    
    cliBusySleepLabel2 = new JLabel("<html><font size=2>(1-999 sec)</font></html>");
    conOptGBC.gridx = 2;
    conOptGBC.gridy = 2;
    conOpt.add(cliBusySleepLabel2, conOptGBC);
    conOpt.setVisible(false);
    contentPanel.add(conOpt);
}
```

My problem is the GridBagConstraints anchor has no effect, my components are still in the center of the panel.

Comment: You are either mis-interpreting the visual result or looking at something which depends on the outer component’s state which we cannot deduce from your code fragment. Can you post a screenshot (together with a textual description of what part you didn’t expect?

Comment: I have edited the post and added a screenshot link.

Comment: The only difference I can see between the red and blue versions could be accounted for by an `EmptyBorder` on the container that holds the components.

Comment: It looks more like the container with the `GridBagLayout` doesn’t have the size you expect. It’s the relationship to its parent which matters. You can add a visible border to `conOptGBC` to verify it. Or just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> inside the window and check the size it the text output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `anchor` property is working correctly, the issue you are having is with...

```
conOptGBC.weightx = 1.0;
conOptGBC.weighty = 1.0;
```

The problem is, you've asked `GridBagLayout` to allocate equal amount of space for each column, so they will take up, in this case, are third each, this is what would be consider.

By removing the `conOptGBC.weightx = 1.0;` you get...

[image: Form]

It's a little difficult to see, but if we add some guides in...

[image: Grid]

You can see that the fields begin to align to the north-west...

Comment: I see thank you. So the text aligns to north-west inside it's cell, but how can I align the cell to the north-west inside my JPanel?

Comment: You could set the `weightx` to `1` one of the components in the last column and I would set the `weighty` to `1` for one of the components in the last row...or you could just add a "invisible" component to the last row/col + 1 and assign the `weightx` and `weighty` to `1` for that component